# Is SwiftUI iOS only or can it be used for other Apple platforms as well?

Tags: swiftui

All the Swift UI tutorials I've seen are iOS based. Is SwiftUI iOS only or can it be used for other Apple hardware platforms as well such as macOS, watchOS, tvOS, and/or iPadOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SwiftUI is available for all Apple platforms. From the the official [SwiftUI homepage](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/swiftui/):

> SwiftUI is an innovative, exceptionally simple way to build user interfaces across all Apple platforms with the power of Swift. Build user interfaces for any Apple device using just one set of tools and APIs.

[image]

[image]